# How to read and convert Kotlin DSL definitions from text file?

Tags: kotlin

I have my Kotlin DSL definitions in static text file or user will provide those DSL definitions as a text content during runtime. How to convert those text content into Kotlin definitions dynamically? So that program can understand as DSL object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Kotlin script engine for that.

The following packages are needed for that:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-util
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable
```

Then you have to create the file `META-INF/services/javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory` with the following content:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngineFactory
```

Once set up you can use the script engine to compile and run Kotlin scripts from within your application like in this small example:

```
with(ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")) {

    val script =
        """
        "Hello World"
        """.trimIndent()


    val scriptResult = eval(script)

    return scriptResult as String

}
```

See the [Kotlin JSR223 Example](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example) for more details on how to use the scripting engine.